# How to convert PNG/JPEG images to svg with ImageMagick?

Tags: svg, colors, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, potrace

It seems that with `potrace` installed, I can just run `magick convert x.png x.svg` or `magick convert x.jpg x.svg`.
However this just returns a deformed image in black and white, and I need the svg image to be in full color. Additionally, I really need the file format to be svg because svg images are small and portable, and I don't have a lot of disk space on my server.
Does anyone know how to convert png/jpeg to svg while retaining color?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1544222/512106

Comment: Who told you that svg images are smaller? A photo? forget it. SVG tend to be small for logos, etc. And it work good (and automatically) just the inverse: SVG to pixels. The contrary way is often complex and you should manually review the result: SVG uses relation between points, which a pixelized image do not have (and reconstruction may fail). In any case, your question is not about programming, so off-topic to this site.